# Display Custom-Post-Types titles in Taxonomy page

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a Book Publisher's website. I've created a CTP called BOOKS and a Custom Taxonomy called WRITERS. I'm working on the taxonomy-writers.php and also added a couple Custom Meta Fields for WRITERS as birth date and a short bio. I also want to display the linked BOOK titles that each WRITER has. I currently have:

```
<?php
get_header();

global $be_themes_data;
while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
?>
<div class="tatsu-module tatsu-text-block-wrap tatsu-34Z1O7zkR  ">
  <div class="tatsu-text-inner tatsu-align-center  clearfix">
    <style>
.tatsu-34Z1O7zkR.tatsu-text-block-wrap .tatsu-text-inner{width: 80%;text-align: left;}
</style>
    <?php
    $term = get_queried_object();

    $taxonomymetafield1 = get_field( 'small-bio', $term );
    $taxonomymetafield2 = get_field( 'birth-date', $term );

    ?>
    <h1 class="category-title"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h1>
    <h5 class="category-title"><?php echo $taxonomymetafield2; ?></h5>
    <p class="category-description"><?php echo $taxonomymetafield1; ?></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php $term = get_queried_object();  ?>
<?php echo $term->taxonomy; ?> Books written:<?php echo $term->count; ?></span>
</h1>
<?php
endwhile;
get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For displaying custom post titles on the taxonomy page. you have to query your custom post type.

```html
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy' 
            'field'    => 'slug', // You can name,slug,term_taxonomy_id as well
            'terms'    => 'your_term_slug', //pass data according to filed
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

after that, loop the query and take title from loop.